# How do I know if a redirect to another website is happening on front end or backend?

Tags: redirect, web-applications

I use a webapp which is integrating third parties webapps, once I click on a service A, it redirects me to the webapp responsible for that service.

How do I locate where is the redirection happening? Front-end or Back-end?